# Attempt to Read Property on String Error Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display data through a query on Codeigniter, but return an error
"ATTEMPT TO READ PROPERTY "JENIS_PRODUK" ON STRING"

Here's my code on controller :

```
public function minimalist($id = 'minimalist')
{
    $data["minimalis"] = $this->welcome_model->getMinimalis($id);
    $this->load->view('frontend/minimalis.php', $data);
}
```

My code on Model :

```
public function getMinimalis($id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["jenis_produk" => $id])->row();
}
```

On view I added `foreach` to display those data

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Please post the view as well, since that's most likely where the error is thrown. It's hard to help fix an issue if we can't see the actual code that causes it. However, your `$data["minimalis"]` only contains one single record, not a list of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this

```
public function getMinimalis($id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["jenis_produk" => $id])->row();
 }
```

To

```
public function getMinimalis($id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["jenis_produk" => $id])->result();
}
```