# I am trying to display data trough Array but is shows error : Attempt to read property " " on string here are my approaches in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

here is all MVC code below error to fetch data

## controller

```
public function bid_data()
       {
            $user   = $this->session->userdata('user');
            $id     = $user['id'];
            $this->load->model('GetModel');
            $data['admin'] = $this->GetModel->auction_data($id);
            
            if(!empty($data['admin'])){
           $this->load->view('user/bidData',$data);
            }else{
               $this->session->set_flashdata('no_record','<b>Sorry</b> No record found !!');
              redirect(base_url().'user/UserSubmit');
            }        
         }
```

im expecting to print data trough row in Array in my views but show error

## view

```
 <?php  foreach($admin as $row): ?>
          <tr style="text-align:center">
         <td class="list"><?php echo $row->sno; ?></td>
         <td class="list"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/bid_result/remove/'.$id ;?>">remove</a></td>
         <td class="list"><a href="">win</a></td>
             </tr>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

## model

```
public function auction_data($id)
        {
              $query = $this->db->get_where('user_bid',['id'=> $id]);
              return $query->row();
           
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the `auction_data` function from your `GetModel`?

Comment: public function auction_data($id)
        {
              $query = $this->db->get_where('user_bid',['id'=> $id]);
              return $query->row();
           
        }

Comment: You're returning a single object from `auction_data` and you can't loop over that (in the view) because it's not an array. Change `->row()` to `->result()` in `auction_data` to return an array instead, see also the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68189351/3960296

Comment: thankyou for your help and Valuable time